# SQL row data mismatch for different users

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I am using MySQL (version 5.5.43) as my database.

I have a RoR micro-service that does an update column to a model Active Record class:

```
model.update_columns(status: 0)
```

The next line is an api call to different micro-service that synchronously does a SQL query:

```
select * from model where status = 0;
```

The code runs without any errors but the latter query is not fetching the record that is being updated by the former. There is milliseconds of difference between the update and the read.

Both the services are connected to the same database as different users but same access.

I don't understand why this would happen? the update_column is obviously a commit to the db, then why would the select query not fetch the updated record. What am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure the update has been done ? can you stop after the call and run straight the query in the db ?

Comment: @farbiondriven I tried this on my local setup with same sql user, one logged in from the rails console (consider this as your application) and another one is a sql client. The update immediately reflected when i ran the query through the client.